# Finding integer solutions of K for equation floor(A/K) = B

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to find integer solutions of K for equation floor(A/K) = B, in terms of A and B where A and B are non-negative integers?

- What I tried:
- floor(A/K) = B
- then B <= A/K < B + 1
- then BK <= A < BK + K
- but I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: What have you tried? What about solving $[5/K]=6$ with an integer $K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lfloor\frac{A}{K}\rfloor=B$ then $\frac{A}{K} - 1 \leq B \leq \frac{A}{K} + 1$, so $\frac{A}{B+1} \leq K \leq \frac{A}{B-1}$

Comment: Can you please explain how you simplified the third equation from the second?

Comment: The second breaks down into two inequalities, isolate for $K$ in each one

Comment: Oh! Got it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: This may not yield an integer solution for $K$ as required.

Comment: The bound on $K$ I gave isn’t the final solution but hopefully enough to get the asker there